# Ionic - ion-nav-bar class="bar-stable" - tab not shown

Tags: ionic-framework

I am building a very simple app that have 2 tabs.
I am mimic the sample provided by ionic web site (tabs).
So I have my main index.html, a tabs.html (for the tab navigation footer) and 2 more html files with the content of the tabs (actually just simple text at the moment).
When I run my application (http://localhost:8100) the page is correctly forwarded to the default tab address (http://localhost:8100/#/tab/b2bviewer) and the tab footer with tabs icons is displayed. But no content in the page.
If I click the second tab (setting) the url change correctly (http://localhost:8100/#/tab/settings) but still blank page.
All this without a single error in the browser console.

So my first question is: how can I troubleshoot such situation? Wrong behaviour and nothing in the log. I added a couple of console.log in my .js but I can just see that the js has been executed.

Second question is: what's wrong in my app!?
Here some bits and pieced of my code:

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="b2bviewerApp">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no, width=device-width">
    <title></title>

    <link href="lib/ionic/css/ionic.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- IF using Sass (run gulp sass first), then uncomment below and remove the CSS includes above
    <link href="css/ionic.app.css" rel="stylesheet">
    -->

    <!-- ionic/angularjs js -->
    <script src="lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js"></script>

    <!-- cordova script (this will be a 404 during development) -->
    <script src="cordova.js"></script>

    <!-- your app's js -->
    <script src="js/app.js"></script>
    <script src="js/controllers.js"></script>  
    <script src="js/services.js"></script>  
  </head>
  <body>

        <!--
        The nav bar that will be updated as we navigate between views.
        -->
        <ion-nav-bar class="bar-stable">
            <ion-nav-back-button>
            </ion-nav-back-button>
        </ion-nav-bar>  

            <!--
            The views will be rendered in the <ion-nav-view> directive below
            Templates are in the /templates folder (but you could also
            have templates inline in this html file if you'd like).
            -->
          <ion-nav-view></ion-nav-view>
  </body>
</html>
```

app.js

```
// Ionic Starter App

console.log("### In app.js ");

// angular.module is a global place for creating, registering and retrieving Angular modules
// 'starter' is the name of this angular module example (also set in a <body> attribute in index.html)
// the 2nd parameter is an array of 'requires'
var b2bviewerApp = angular.module('b2bviewerApp', ['ionic', 'b2bviewerApp.controllers', 'b2bviewerApp.services'])

.run(function($ionicPlatform) {
  $ionicPlatform.ready(function() {
    // Hide the accessory bar by default (remove this to show the accessory bar above the keyboard
    // for form inputs)
    if(window.cordova && window.cordova.plugins.Keyboard) {
      cordova.plugins.Keyboard.hideKeyboardAccessoryBar(true);
    }
    if(window.StatusBar) {
      StatusBar.styleDefault();
    }
  });
})

.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {

    // Ionic uses AngularUI Router which uses the concept of states
    // Learn more here: https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router
    // Set up the various states which the app can be in.
    // Each state's controller can be found in controllers.js
    $stateProvider

    // setup and abstract state fot the tabs directive
    .state('tab', {
        url: "/tab",
        abstract: true,
        templateUrl: "templates/tabs.html"
    })

    // each tab has its own nav history stack:
    .state('tab.b2bviewer', {
        url: '/b2bviewer',
        cache: false,
        view: {
            'tab-b2bviewer': {
                templateUrl: 'templates/tab-b2bviewer.html',
                controller: 'B2bviewerController'
            }
        }
    })

    .state('tab.settings', {
        url: '/settings', 
        cache: false,
        view: {
            'tab-settings': {
                templateUrl: 'templates/tab-settings.html',
                controller: 'SettingsController'
            }
        }
    });

    // if none of the above states are matched, use this as the fallback
    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/tab/b2bviewer');

});
```

controller.js

```
angular.module('b2bviewerApp.controllers', [])

.controller('B2bviewerController', function($scope){
    console.log("### In controllers.js - B2bviewerController");
})    

.controller('SettingsController', function($scope){
    console.log("### In controllers.js - SettingsController");
});

console.log("### In controllers.js");
```

tabs.html

```
<ion-tabs class="tabs-icon-top tabs-color-active-positive">

  <!-- b2bviewer Tab -->
  <ion-tab title="b2bviewr" icon-off="ion-ios-pulse" icon-on="ion-ios-pulse-strong" href="#/tab/b2bviewer">
    <ion-nav-view name="tab-b2bviewr"></ion-nav-view>
  </ion-tab>

  <!-- Settings Tab -->
  <ion-tab title="Settgins" icon-off="ion-ios-gear-outline" icon-on="ion-ios-gear" href="#/tab/settings">
    <ion-nav-view name="tab-settings"></ion-nav-view>
  </ion-tab>

</ion-tabs>
```

settings.html

```
<ion-view view-title="Settings">
  <ion-content class="padding">
    <div class="list card">
      <div class="item item-divider">Recent Updates</div>
      <div class="item item-body">
        <div>
          There is a fire in <b>sector 3</b>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </ion-content>
</ion-view>
```

Any help is help is much appreciated.

Giovanni

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a few problems with your code.

When you define a state you specify a view using `views` instead of `view`:

```
.state('tab.b2bviewer', {
    url: '/b2bviewer',
    cache: false,
    views: {
        'tab-b2bviewer': {
            templateUrl: 'templates/tab-b2bviewer.html',
            controller: 'B2bviewerController'
        }
    }
})
```

You don't have the template **tab-b2bviewer.html** (or maybe you haven't included here).

You have misspelled your views's name in the tab:

```
<!-- b2bviewer Tab -->
<ion-tab title="b2bviewr" icon-off="ion-ios-pulse" icon-on="ion-ios-pulse-strong" href="#/tab/b2bviewer">
  <ion-nav-view name="tab-b2bviewr"></ion-nav-view>
</ion-tab>
```

You've used **tab-b2bviewr** and it should be **tab-b2bviewr**.

You can check an adaptation of your code [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/ij8GqSRvyNSGGo6VFBA5?p=preview).

Comment: Hi Man... you are the man!
The problem was the 'view' instead of 'views'.

Now ... the first question! How did you find that? Did you just went through the code and because you are the whole js/ionic enciclopedia in your brain you saw the error reading my code? Or you put some breakpoint/control/whatever to spot the problem?

Comment: @GiovanniVigorelli: I am afraid you cannot spot these kind of problems cause there's no way to debug them. I guess the way to figure out weird behaviours is to check the spelling of most names. I put your code in a plunker and when through all the bits and found that :-)

Comment: @GiovanniVigorelli: feel free to up-vote me if you're happy with the answer. cheers.

Comment: ...just did. Not really familiar with stackoverflow. Thanks again.